# Can we add widget for app in iOS and if not ,is there any alternative?

Tags: ios, ios7

I came to know that iOS does't support widgets this is what i have read.But i am making application on Security in iOS, i want the user to perform some action when he is in need of help without opening the application.
I know iOS supports few background modes like play audio,receive location updates,voip etc.
Can anyone suggest me any alternative to fire some methods without opening the application like pressing some button when in dangerous situation to call those methods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether we can do it or not.

But have a look.

You said we can implement background modes like audio, location, voip updates etc.

Let take the example of Audio mode. It has previous, play/pause, and next button in the lockscreen.

What you can do is play an audio when the application is in background mode.

Check whether the any of the music buttons are pressed more than 3 times. If this is the case trigger alert messages for security and send them to appropriate persons or do your own action.

I don't know whether we can do this or not. Even if it is possible, I can't say Apple will allow such false actions for buttons which are meant for some purpose.

**Also see whether we can get detect volume button presses when in background mode. If that is possible you can do that. Because even my LG mobile has an SOS mode which is enabled when I press volume buton in lockscreen 4 times.** Apple may allow this action if it possible